# Omit axes with facet_grid - plotnine

Tags: python, ggplot2, axes, plotnine

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1],'B':[1,9,5,11],'C':['x','x','y','y'],'D':['a','b','a','b']})
p=ggplot(df,aes('A','B'))
p + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid('D~C',scales='free_y')
```

This will draw axes on both the left and right grids. Is there a way to omit the axes on the right grids, such that it is only visible on the left? I know I could use `scales="fixed"` but I would like them to vary between rows.

Answer (score 0):

It is misleading to have free scales for all panels yet have ticks and labels for only some of them. But if you really want to, you have to drop into Matplotlib for that

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1],'B':[1,9,5,11],'C':['x','x','y','y'],'D':['a','b','a','b']})
p=ggplot(df,aes('A','B'))
p = p + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid('D~C',scales='free_y')
fig, p = p.draw(return_ggplot=True)
for i, ax in enumerate(p.axs):
    if i % 2:
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not what I meant. I'm trying to get plotnine to display the left axis only, but adjusting the bar heights appropriately. In my example, that would mean having the top left axis to a ymax of 5 and adjust the height of the top left bar to 1. If you run my example code with the ggplot2 package, that's the result you'll get.